# Issue in image formatting in 3D cone in Three.js

Tags: three.js

I'm using CylinderGeometry to create a 3D cone.

I'm using `ImageUtils.loadTexture` to load the images on bottom and curve surface of the cone.

```
var mat1 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color : 0xcccccc , map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( 'textures/CIRCLE_1.png' ), overdraw: true } );     
var mat2 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color : 0xcccccc , map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( 'textures/LABEL.png' ), overdraw: true } );
```

The curve surface image is getting squeezed up to fit the cone.

Can I choose a portion of the image to be displayed in the cone without displaying the rest part of the image.

Or else ,if we provide a triangular image , it creates a hollow looking cone as the transparent portion of the image also comes up while rendering the cone.

I'm not able to attach images along this post.

Answer (score 0):

For choosing a portion of the image you would have to modify the UV coordinates. I dont know how easy that would be. Another way is to just modify the image to your liking in gimp or photoshop.

Comment: Even if I modify the image in photoshop,the image will have white/ transaprent boundaries which ll create the same old unwanted effect. UV coordinate modification might be the way out, but don't hav any idea regarding this. Please help. Any example code will help a lot

Comment: We need to know what you are getting know and what is the desired effect. In addition it will probably be easier to find the UV mappings on a plane instead of a cone and then move to the cone.

Comment: Currently the cone takes the entire image to paint the curved surface. The desired result ll be to paint only the part of image that has the image leaving the blank or transparent portion.

Comment: Currently the cone takes the entire image to paint the curved surface. The desired result ll be to paint only the part of image that has the image leaving the blank or transparent portion.

I mean to say, The image provided for the cone slant surface is like a sector of a circle. The rest part is whitened. I need to remove the whitend part of the image while painting it on the curved surface of the cone.